# The color of MeshMatcapMaterial looks very light?

Tags: three.js, shader

I use MeshMatcapMaterial in threejs for rendering

```
const matCapMaterial = new THREE.MeshMatcapMaterial({
      matcap: matcapTexture
})
```

Here are the texture and result

The color is supppose to be darker

How can I fix this

Thanks !

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a colorspace encoding issue. Hard to tell for certain with such little code, but maybe you'd like to change from the default `THREE.LinearEncoding` to sRGB colorspace:

```js
matcapTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;

const matCapMaterial = new THREE.MeshMatcapMaterial({
      matcap: matcapTexture
});
```

[See the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.encoding) for more details on texture encoding.

Comment: Nice ! it works . Just set the texture encoding to THREE.sRGBEncoding

Answer (score 0):

**2023 Update:**

The updated answer as of **Three.js version** `0.158.1`

```
   texture.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
```

Source: [Documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.colorSpace)